# Why does Kate look like this?

Tags: fonts, text-editor, kate

Why does Kate look like this? The lines are mounting. I tryed unistall but the problem persist. :(

[image]

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS - KDE

Comment: Exit kate and run `locate kate | grep home` to find all user-related files related to kate. Rename them with a `.bak` suffix and see whether kate appears normal then.